# Clojure: How can I take a list of functions, transform them, and return a map with their original names?

Tags: clojure

Ok, so say I have a list of functions:
[f1 f2 f3]

I also have a transforming function, we'll call it 'trans'

What I want to do is apply trans to every function in my original list, and return a map whose keys are symbols corresponding to the original fxn names, and whose values are the transformed versions of those functions:

```
{:f1 (trans f1) :f2 (trans f2) :f3 (trans f3)}
```

This is probably a really easy question, but I am having trouble getting at the metadata needed to turn the function name into a symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your initial list contains actual functions, as opposed to Vars holding functions or symbols which resolve to such Vars, then in general there is no canonical way to assign names to them, as functions in Clojure may not necessarily have a name. You could take the name of the class of a function object and process it like [clj-stacktrace](https://github.com/mmcgrana/clj-stacktrace) does to get something like a human-readable "name", but it may not be possible to go from that to the function. So, when dealing with lists of functions, you may want to consider providing an explicit list of names.

If your list contained symbols instead, you could do

```
(zipmap fs (map (comp trans deref resolve) fs))
```

where `fs` is the input list to produce a map with the members of `fs` as keys and the transformed functions stored in the Vars named by the members of `fs` as the values. (If you'd rather transform the symbols to keywords to match the desired output displayed in the question text, you can use `(map keyword fs)` as the first argument to `zipmap`.)

Similarly, if you had a list of Vars, you could extract the namespaces and symbolic names from the Vars (using interop forms to access the relevant fields of `clojure.lang.Var`, namely `sym` and `ns`) while using `deref` to get at the functions to be fed to `trans`. (Strictly speaking, a Var may have no namespace or symbolic name attached to it -- see `with-local-vars`; such Vars are not used very frequently though, so you can reasonably make it part of your list transformation's contract that it expects not to find any in its input.)

Answer (score 0):

You can try a macro as shown below. You will need to pass the function list directly to the macro.

```
(defmacro fn-to-map [fns trans-fn]
  `~(into {} (map #(-> [(-> % name keyword) `(~trans-fn ~%)]) fns)))
```

Example:

```
(let [f1 inc
      f2 dec
      f3 print]
  (fn-to-map [f1 f2 f3] identity))
```